# C# Lucene Index File size increasing on adding files

Tags: c#, indexing, lucene, lucene.net

Below are the 2 components of the application

1. C# Web service which reads data from lucene index
2. C# Windows Service is updating data inside index file

Index File size 1.2 GB.

When Service is updating data it is creating duplicate file and files are getting increased. There are very frequent reads. Sometime updates to index.

Due to duplication the file size sometimes goes till 100 GB and i am getting disk full exception.

I have checked reader are disposed quickly with Using block.

How can i delete unused files to keep index directory file size smaller?

Comment: What version of Lucene.NET is it? What code is causing this to happen?

Comment: @NightOwl888 .net framework 4.5 and lucene 3.0.3

Comment: @AjayNikam Have you tried optimising after the update?

Comment: I have tried did not helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution for the problem by trying multiple things.

If we update index with small and very high frequent updates then lucene keep creating files and increases file size so now I am waiting for complete group of updates and updating index in bulk. With this approach lucene is not creating multiple copies of files. there are 3 to 4 times more files where earlier it was more than 70 to 80 times.

In short update index in bulk, no small and frequent updates.